# Why do i need to use current.load() rather than just .load()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

After looking at the React documentation of how to use refs, once the ref is set up and linked to a DOM node, it states to, for instance get the DOM node to reload (in my case when using a HMTL5 video tag) you have to do for example `this.videoRef.current.load()` rather than simply `this.videoRef.load()`. Does anyone know what this current property does/represents, and why it is neccessary? After trying both cases my code only works with the former.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [React Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) we can see that when a RefContainer is created it's initial value is actually passed to this *.current* property for the full life time of the component. In other words the actual DOM node you passed to your refContainer isn't passed to the object itself but rather to it's *.current* property. So when you call the load() method on the containerRef object itself it won't execute because it isn't set to a value.